# Ul li Column Count with If Condition in Less Or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, less

I am using column counter in ul li. i want 15 numbers in one counter li and then i want 15-15 li in each counter group. i have also share pic what i need actual.

is it possible in jQuery or Less Or JavaScript ??

thanks in advance.

Attachment : [Images1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax78O.jpg)

jsfiddle link : [link1](https://jsfiddle.net/rmheqd0b/)

```css
.counter-list{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0px;
  column-count: 2;
}
.counter-list li {
     
}
```

```html
<ul class="counter-list">
<li>list 1</li><li>list 2</li><li>list 3</li><li>list 4</li><li>list 5</li><li>list 6</li><li>list 7</li>
<li>list 8</li><li>list 9</li><li>list 10</li><li> list 11</li><li>list 12</li><li>list 13</li>
<li>list 14</li><li>list 15</li><li>list 16</li><li>list 17</li><li>list 18</li><li>list 19</li>
<li>list 20</li><li> list 21</li><li>list 22</li><li>list 23</li>
<li>list 24</li><li>list 25</li><li>list 26</li><li>list 27</li><li>list 28</li><li>list 29</li>
<li>list 30</li><li>list 31</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code: (Just change min_items_per_col)

```js
$(function($) {
    var num_cols = 0,
    container = $('.counter-list'),
    listItem = 'li',
    listClass = 'sub-list';
    container.each(function() {
        var items_per_col = new Array(),
        items = $(this).find(listItem),
        min_items_per_col = 15,//Math.floor(items.length / num_cols),
        num_cols = Math.ceil((items.length) / min_items_per_col),
        difference = items.length - (min_items_per_col * num_cols);

        for (var i = 0; i < num_cols; i++) {
            if (i < difference) {
                items_per_col[i] = min_items_per_col + 1;
            } else {
                items_per_col[i] = min_items_per_col;
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < num_cols; i++) {
            $(this).append($('<ul ></ul>').addClass(listClass));
            for (var j = 0; j < items_per_col[i]; j++) {
                var pointer = 0;
                for (var k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                    pointer += items_per_col[k];
                }
                $(this).find('.' + listClass).last().append(items[j + pointer]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.counter-list ul{
  float: left;
  list-style:none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
.counter-list li{
  line-height: 1.5em;
  counter-increment: step-counter;
 }
.counter-list li:before {
    content: counter(step-counter);
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 80%;
  background-color: rgb(0,200,200);
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
 }
```

```html
<ul class="counter-list">

  <li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li><li>List</li>
</ul>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: hi @vaibhav thanks for your answer but i have faceout some issue. please check jsfiddle link > this is first issue https://jsfiddle.net/hwrepzu2/ this is second issue :https://jsfiddle.net/hwrepzu2/1/

Comment: I have updated the above script please recheck now and tell me if you face any issues again

Comment: @GauravK check this fiddle now, I have removed the hardcoded values https://jsfiddle.net/8tjk4hL2/2/

Comment: dear @vaibhav, when i add more li same issue happen, In my side (Actually no limit of li because number of li add dynamic.) . can you adjust these li, when adding more & more ??

Comment: @GauravK you need to adjust the padding and margin thats it as I have adjusted the css can you please recheck. Also I have added the border to bottom when the container width rechaes it will start remaining items below it, you can check by resizing the result window here https://jsfiddle.net/3cudv4gz/2/

Comment: @GauravK instead on fiddle please check on your local machine.(don't forget to add jquery). You will see the result more accurately and adjust the css accordingly.

Comment: yes Thanks a lot @Vaibhav, Its great work for me. you are the superman of the jQuery.

Comment: Dear @Vaibhav Can you share your code in stack overflow with proper formate, because I want to vote for your code with green check sign

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209701/discussion-between-gaurav-k-and-vaibhav-gidde).

Answer (score 3):

I change your CSS to display 15 items. See below example.

```css
.counter-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(15, 1fr);
}

.counter-list li {}
```

```html
<ul class="counter-list">
  <li>list 1</li>
  <li>list 2</li>
  <li>list 3</li>
  <li>list 4</li>
  <li>list 5</li>
  <li>list 6</li>
  <li>list 7</li>
  <li>list 8</li>
  <li>list 9</li>
  <li>list 10</li>
  <li> list 11</li>
  <li>list 12</li>
  <li>list 13</li>
  <li>list 14</li>
  <li>list 15</li>
  <li>list 16</li>
  <li>list 17</li>
  <li>list 18</li>
  <li>list 19</li>
  <li>list 20</li>
  <li> list 21</li>
  <li>list 22</li>
  <li>list 23</li>
  <li>list 24</li>
  <li>list 25</li>
  <li>list 26</li>
  <li>list 27</li>
  <li>list 28</li>
  <li>list 29</li>
  <li>list 30</li>
  <li>list 31</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: hey thanks for share your code, @shree cross browser compatible problem. check https://caniuse.com/#search=grid-template-rows%3A