# How to control the columns based on the menus in Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, conditional-statements

I want to display the menus as separate columns if its more than 4 menus. I need to achieve this in Vanilla Javascript. Below is my html and CSS and I'm not sure how to achieve this in Vanilla Javascript. Can anyone please guide?

```css
.main-nav-list.column{
    column-count: 2;
        column-fill: balance;}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">

    <ul class="main-nav-list">
        <li class="a"> <a href="/">First</a>
            <ul class="main-nav-list">
                <li class="b"> <a href="/">Type of menu</a>
                    <ul class="main-nav-list column">
                        <li class="c"> <a href="/">Summer</a> </li>
                        <li class="c"> <a href="/">Winter</a> </li>
                        <li class="c"> <a href="/">All season</a> </li>
                        <li class="c"> <a href="/">Spring </a> </li>
                                                <li class="c"> <a href="/">Spring </a> </li>
                                                                        <li class="c"> <a href="/">Spring </a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in client-side(?) JavaScript? If the menu does not get created/manipulated on the client - then why don't you have the server set an appropriate class already, when it generates this menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Separate columns based on the Menus, you can try the below script,

```js
  (function columnCount() {
    //get all lists with selected name
    var lists = document.getElementsByClassName("column");

    //loop through all gathered lists
    for (i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
      //shorthand elements for easy use
      var list = lists[i];
      var items = list.getElementsByTagName("li");

      list.className += items.length < 5 ? " lesscolumn" : " morecolumn";
    }
  })();
```

```css
  .lesscolumn {
    column-count: 1;
  }
  .morecolumn {
    column-count: 2;
  }
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">

    <ul class="main-nav-list">
        <li class="a"> <a href="/">First</a>
            <ul class="main-nav-list">
                <li class="b"> <a href="/">Type of menu</a>
                    <ul class="main-nav-list column">
                        <li class="c"> <a href="/">Summer</a> </li>
                        <li class="c"> <a href="/">Winter</a> </li>
                        <li class="c"> <a href="/">All season</a> </li>
                        <li class="c"> <a href="/">Spring </a> </li>
                                                <li class="c"> <a href="/">Spring </a> </li>
                                                                        <li class="c"> <a href="/">Spring </a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Great. It's working. You saved my time!!!

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `display: grid` property.

```css
.main-nav-list.column {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">

  <ul class="main-nav-list">
    <li class="a"> <a href="/">First</a>
      <ul class="main-nav-list">
        <li class="b"> <a href="/">Type of menu</a>
          <ul class="main-nav-list column">
            <li class="c"> <a href="/">Summer</a> </li>
            <li class="c"> <a href="/">Winter</a> </li>
            <li class="c"> <a href="/">All season</a> </li>
            <li class="c"> <a href="/">Spring </a> </li>
            <li class="c"> <a href="/">Spring </a> </li>
            <li class="c"> <a href="/">Spring </a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I have already referred this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60701490/ul-li-column-count-with-if-condition-in-less-or-jquery but I want to achieve this in Javascript.

Comment: you've looked yourself to a particular implementation, you should try other approaches instead of insisting on a particular approach

Comment: Are you getting the list of menu items in some kind of array? if yes then maybe we can render the menu links from the array and split it into a bunch of 4 elements.